# Why does my regular expression grab the EOLN as well?

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to write a batch file to automate bulk edits of some Pascal source.  I have source files with the occasional line like this one:

```
     //{## identifier} Inc (Index) ; { a comment }    // another comment
```

and I want to change them all to:

```
     {$ifdef identifier} Inc (Index) ; { a comment }    // another comment {$endif}
```

Below is a test batch file I'm using.

```
:: File TestRXRepl.bat
:: ===================     

@echo     //{##   identifier} Inc (Index) ; { a comment }    // another comment >t.pas
@set "FindRegExp=(\ *)\/\/\{\#\#\ *([a-z,0-9,_]+)\}(\ *)(.*)"
@set "ReplRegExp=\1{$ifdef \2}\3\4 {$endif}"

rxrepl --file t.pas --output t.out --search "%FindRegExp%" --replace "%ReplRegExp%"
@type t.pas
@type t.out
```

The regular expression is supposed to:

- capture leading indent (group 1)
- match `//{##`
- skip any spaces
- capture an identifier (group 2)
- match `}`
- capture the source code indent (group 3)
- capture the source line from then on to the end of the line (group 4)

Everything works except the end-of-line handling.  Group 4 is supposed to capture everything from the start of the source line up until the end of line but it seems to *include* the end of line with the result being that the `{endif}` is written to the next line, i.e. I get:

```
{$ifdef identifier} Inc (Index) ; { a comment }    // another comment
{$endif}
```

rather than:

```
{$ifdef identifier} Inc (Index) ; { a comment }    // another comment {$endif}
```

The tool I am using is [RXRepl](https://sites.google.com/site/regexreplace/).  It has an option `--eol` which sounds like it might be useful, but I couldn't alter the behaviour with using it.

(Notes)

- I know both results are syntactically correct, but that's not the
  point ;-)
- Groups 3 and 4 could be combined.
- it doesn't handle other white space characters.
- There are classier ways of matching an identifier, I know.

Suggestions to make it more elegant are welcome, as well as suggestions to make it work right.

Comment: Does it work if you end the match in `(.*\S)` as the fourth group? Or `(\N*)` might work, for a different way to match `.` that won't include a newline character... Does your file have DOS (CR/LF) or Unix (LF only) newlines? It's possible the issue is related to newline format...

Comment: Bullseye.  Both worked.  Platform is Windows, files are CRLF-delimited.

Like to make that an answer?

Comment: Yeah, will do! I wonder if adding `(*CRLF)` to the start of the regex would have helped as well... https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#newlines But if `\N` worked, that means DOTALL is in effect, so no I don't think that would have helped. I'll write an answer shortly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that your `.` is matching the newline, which means the PCRE2_DOTALL option is in effect. (I don't know why that's the case here, it's possible that `rxrepl` always sets that option by default.)

One possible way to work around that is to end group 4 in your regular expression match with `(.*\S)`, using the [`\S` character type](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#genericchartypes) which will match any character that's not a whitespace, and that will exclude the newline character(s).

But probably the best way to fix this is to use [the `\N` sequence](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#genericchartypes), which is described in the manual as:

> The `\N` escape sequence has the same meaning as the "`.`" metacharacter when `PCRE2_DOTALL` is not set, but setting `PCRE2_DOTALL` does not change the meaning of `\N`.

So just using `(\N*)` for group 4 in your match will match everything it's currently matching, except for the trailing newline.

In your script, simply update this line:

```
@set "FindRegExp=(\ *)\/\/\{\#\#\ *([a-z,0-9,_]+)\}(\ *)(\N*)"
```